# How to get values from properties file in grails?

Tags: grails

How to get values from properties file please? and where should I put the file ?
Thank you

EDIT : I'm using grails 3.1.5 And I'm trying to get properties from a job class (quartz)

Comment: why down vote? I've searched but didn't find where I should put the file ...

Comment: Thank you I've edited my answer, can the downvoter please take off his downvote because this caused me to get bannned from asking questions...

Comment: sounds  bizarre way of doing it? why don't you define the config properly in application.groovy or application.yml then call the config in job and where ever else needed .  follow this link and when the files are in src/groovy https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/search?p=3&q=config&utf8=%E2%9C%93 is what you need to follow for configuring your job to call application.groovy or application.yml config and maybe easier to follow a service from here to see it used in service controller https://github.com/vahidhedayati/mailinglist/search?p=1&q=config

Comment: Oh thank you, by the way I think that the job will call services any way, what I'm trying to do is to make "the delay between sending two emails (alert email)" configurable, so I want to retrieve this delay from a config file, this will allow a non-developper to be able to configure the app, what's the right way to do it ? Isn't it better to keep this away from "developpers config" like application.groovy and application.yml

Comment: oh I'm really sorry, for example if I sell this app to someone and he wants to configure it, so only who have access to the server configuration files, and I may also make it available from the admin cpanel (that I will make), but now all what I care about is when someone buy the app he will be able to configure it for his clients needs, I hope I have been clear enough

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ManvendraSK/8b166b47514ca817d36e  http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/grails-goodness-using-external.html updated with more useful links

Comment: thank you again :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either keep your properties directly in **Config.groovy** file.

Or you can create a **.properties** file to keep properties and add this file in **Config.groovy**

> grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:grails-app-config.properties"]

and access it anywhere in application using

> grailsApplication.config."propertyName"

Comment: Thank you, but where should I put the .properties file?

Comment: You can keep it in conf folder itself

Comment: grails.config.locations is currently not supported in Grails 3. There is a plugin in the making, see https://github.com/sbglasius/external-config

Comment: release version 1.0 from the mentioned plugin is now available.

Answer (score 0):

We have a trait like this:

```
/**
 * Load config from config locations given by property grails.config.locations.
 * Based on http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-3-External-config-td4658823.html
 */
trait ExternalConfigurationLoader implements EnvironmentAware {

    @Override
    void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        loadExternalConfigLocations(environment)
    }

    void loadExternalConfigLocations(Environment environment) {
        if (environment) {
            def configLocations = findConfigLocationsFromApplicationGroovy()
            DefaultResourceLocator resourceLocator = new DefaultResourceLocator()
            for (String configLocation in configLocations) {
                loadConfigLocation(configLocation, grails.util.Environment.current.name, environment, resourceLocator)
            }
        }
    }

    List<String> findConfigLocationsFromApplicationGroovy() {
        def applicationGroovy = this.getClass().classLoader.getResource('application.groovy')
        if (applicationGroovy) {
            def applicationConfiguration = new ConfigSlurper(grails.util.Environment.current.name).parse(applicationGroovy)
            return applicationConfiguration.grails.config.locations
        }
        []
    }

    void loadConfigLocation(String configLocation, String currentEnvironmentName, Environment environment, ResourceLocator resourceLocator) {
        def configurationResource = resourceLocator.findResourceForURI(configLocation)
        if (configurationResource) {
            log.debug "External config '$configLocation' found. Loading."
            def configSlurper = new ConfigSlurper(currentEnvironmentName)
            def config = configSlurper.parse(configurationResource.getURL())
            environment.propertySources.addFirst(new MapPropertySource(configLocation, config))
        } else {
            log.debug "External config '$configLocation' not found."
        }
    }

}
```

Then we can add this trait to `Application.groovy`:

```
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration implements ExternalConfigurationLoader {
```

and configure external config files in `application.groovy`:

```
grails.config.locations = ["classpath:myapp-config.groovy", "file:dev-config.groovy"]
```

If using Tomcat, you can then put `myapp-config.groovy` in Tomcats `lib` folder.

Note: this variant only supports external config files of type `.groovy` but you can extend it to support `.yml` or `.properties` if you prefer that. Also note that this example has some issues with overriding values from environment block in application.yml, so if you plan to override `dataSource` you will need to move the default configuration of `dataSource` from `application.yml` to `application.groovy` first.

There is also a plugin in the making that is adding similar support for `grails.config.locations`. See https://github.com/sbglasius/external-config